# C# Windows FOrms Web Services

Tags: c#, web-service

Gostaria de saber se é possivel trabalhar com web services utilizando a aplicação feita em windows forms. É possível ? Se sim teria alguma referência que possa me ajudar a resolver isso ?

Comment: Você quer consumir um webservice usando Windows Forms? Se sim, claro que é possível! Qual tipo de webservice você pretende consumir?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34924/discussion-between-yuri-ancelmo-and-jbueno).

Comment: No projeto, selecione "Add Web Reference" e coloque a sua url. O Visual Studio cria as estruturas para você consumir o serviço.

Answer (score 2):

Consumindo `Webservices` em Aplicações `WindowsForms`

Para consumir um webservices(considerando que os mesmos sejam providos pelo framework .net) você deve seguir as seguintes etapas:

- Clique com o botão direito em `Referências`(References) e a seguir em `Adicionar Referência  de Serviço`(Add Service Reference ou Web Reference).
- Informe o endereço do webservice (.asmx ou .svc) e clique em descobrir.
- Nesta etapa a janela abaixo já estará atualizada com os métodos permitidos.
- Selecione os métodos desejados e informe o namespace desejado para as chamados do serviço ex: `MeuProjeto.Integracoes.Parcerias`.
- Considerando que você tenha obtido sucesso nas etapas acima você poderá utilizar os webservices como classes internas do seu sistema através do namespace que você atribuiu na etapa anterior.

Havendo quaisquer dúvidas não hesite em apontar que irei atualizar a pergunta com as informações.